# Sum/Total multiple criteria in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to calculate a total for all the data in column B into a single cell

Example:

Column/Row B2 is a PASS
Column/Row B3 is a FAIL
Column/Row B4 is   NA
Column/Row B5 is a PASS
Column/Row B6 is a Pass And Fail
Column/Row B7 is a Fail
Column/Row B8 is   NA
Column/Row B9 is a Fail

In Column/Row B10, I want it to display how many passed, failed and NA. All in the same cell. I currently have the following formula but it counts the text and has them totaled into a number.

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B9,"*")
```

So in this case I would want the cell to display 3PASS,4FAIL, 2NA

Is this possible? I would be applying this formula to other cells as well.

Comment: Will the values always be PASS FAIL NA or do you need to build something dynamically?

Comment: it will always be pass fail and NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set of values are fixed you can write

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(B:B,"PASS"), "PASS, ", COUNTIF(B:B,"FAIL"), "FAIL, ",  COUNTIF(B:B,"NA"), "NA")
```

Comment: Some side comments: I'd generally not advise stuffing things into one cell like this since it allows for less flexibility later. Also when talking about it you can just say "Cell B7" instead of "Column/Row B7".

Comment: Understood thank you for the side comments. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks a million Jeff!